# Calculate the number of active clients for each month (SQL)

Tags: sql

i'm currently doing a query for my job and I need a little bit of help with it.
My database is really simple

| client_id | status | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | active | 2020-01-01 | 2020-03-15 |
| 1 | inactive | 2020-03-15 | null |
| 2 | active | 2020-01-01 | null |
| 3 | active | 2020-01-01 | 2021-04-28 |
| 3 | inactive | 2021-04-28 | 2020-07-28 |
| 3 | active | 2021-07-28 | null |

For each new status of a given client, the database will have a new line and the previous will be updated. There are many different statuses that a client can be in but this is irrelevent for this case.

i need to get, for each month, the number of active clients and i'm a bit struguling with it. I've tried using a partition and i can give the active clients for a range of dates but do not have the monthly distribution.

Can anyone give my some advice :)

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tag your database so this may not work for you (however it is similar in all changing function names, and say lateral to cross apply in SQL server - generate_series could be expressed in a different way in your database). This is basically postgreSQL:

```
select client_id, extract(year from d) y, extract(month from d) m
from MyInfo t1,
     lateral (select generate_series(make_date(cast(extract(year from t1.start_date) as int),
                                               cast(extract(month from t1.start_date) as int), 1),
                                     case when end_date is null then current_date else end_date end,
                                     '1 month'::interval)
) Days(d)
where t1.status = 'active'
order by client_id, y, m;
```

Sample [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f60bae1e4da41a227509f991d14cd3e9)

EDIT: Noticed you were asking for monthly counts. Can be written easier, but expanding the above:

```
with baseData as
         (
             select client_id, extract(year from d) y, extract(month from d) m
             from MyInfo t1,
                  lateral (select generate_series(make_date(cast(extract(year from t1.start_date) as int),
                                                            cast(extract(month from t1.start_date) as int), 1),
                                                  case when end_date is null then current_date else end_date end,
                                                  '1 month'::interval)
                      ) Days(d)
             where t1.status = 'active'
         )
select y, m, count(*)
from baseData
group by y,m
order by y,m;
```

EDIT: Another way:

```
select m, count(*)
from (select generate_series(min(start_date), current_date, '1 month'::interval) from MyInfo) months(m)
         inner join MyInfo i on
            m >= date_trunc('month', i.start_date) and
            m <= date_trunc('month', case when end_date is null then current_date else end_date end)
where i.status = 'active'
group by m
order by m;
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you so much for the answer but, as you mentionned I didn't specify that i'm not using postgreSQL but mysql8
I'll try to use what you've send and modify it a bit to be able to use it 
You rock !